# JavaScript Erro "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')"

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, typeerror, responsive, gallery

I'm trying my hands on a filterable image gallery with class menu, which is expected to isolate only the specified class when clicked. I've written out the HTML CSS and the JavaScript end. However, when I clicked on the button on the Html end, the JavaScript respond with the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')". I've checked online for possible solutions but none of them have been able to solve my problem.

My HTML Code excerpt is

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<main class="Container">
   <section class="btns"> 
        <ul>
            <li class="btn" data-filter = "all">All</li>
            <li class="btn" data-filter="shoe">Shoes</li>
            <li class="btn" data-filter="clothe">Clothes</li>
            <li class="btn" data-filter="hat">Hats</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="gallery">
        <div class="prod" data-item="hat">
            <div class="imgBox">
                <img src="Prod1.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prod" data-item="Shoe">
            <div class="imgBox">
                <img src="Prod2.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prod" data-item="clothe">
            <div class="imgBox">
                <img src="Prod3.png">
            </div>
        </div>
   </section>
</main>
</body>
<html>
```

Javascript Codes

```
var allFilters = document.querySelectorAll('section.btns li.btn');
var allCards = document.querySelectorAll('section.gallery div.prod');

for (var i = 0; i < allFilters.length; i++) {
allFilters[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction);
}

function myFunction(){
    var currentTab = document.querySelector('section.btns .active');
    currentTab.classList.remove('active');
    this.classList.add('active');

    var filter = this.getAttribute('data-filter');

    if (filter != 'all') {
        for (let i = 0; i < allCards.length; i++) {
            allCards[i].classList.add('hide');
            allCards[i].classList.remove('active');
            var currentItem = allCards[i].getAttribute('data-item');
            if (currentItem == filter) {
                allCards[i].classList.add('active');
                allCards[i].classList.remove('hide');
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (let i = 0; i < allCards.length; i++) {
            allCards[i].classList.remove('hide');
            allCards[i].classList.add('active');
        }
    }
}
```

When i execute this and lick on the button, nothing happens but when I View Page Source from the         browser, I notice the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading  'classList')

Answer (score 0):

If there's no active button, `currentTab` will be `null` and you'll get an error when you try to remove the class. Add a check for this.

```
    var currentTab = document.querySelector('section.btns .active');
    if (currentTab) {
      currentTab.classList.remove('active');
    }
```